# alternative to jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, validation, modal-dialog

I am currently a site that is highly dependent on some ui features via javascript. For example to ability to validate a web form or opening a modal pop up. I am working with jquery. In the past I have used jquery ui for such but I am now looking at other options. The main reason for such is due to size of the jquery ui js file which I feel is large for the few feautres I use. I understand the file contains other ui features that I do not need.

Any suggestions to ui validation and modal pop up frameworks?

Comment: You know you can customize the jquery ui file to only have the components you want to use, right?

Answer (score 8):

I highly recommend [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/). They have a very solid code and it's more crossbrowser than jQuery UI. Besides it has a beautiful and modern style (also customizable). Take at look at the [demos](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/).

Comment: Would be helpful to point out that Kendo is a paid product.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher Kendo has an [open source version](http://www.telerik.com/download/kendo-ui-web-open-source) as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can [customize the jQuery UI build/download to only what you need to slim](http://jqueryui.com/download) the file size down.

If you are already doing that and aren't satisfied you might check out [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html).

Comment: Always a great option; I don't understand why people don't do this more often.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fantastic list of useful and absolutely tiny JavaScript frameworks and libraries over at [Microjs](http://microjs.com/).  Chances are pretty good they have something for your needs.

Comment: Nice site! I'll be looking some of those over myself. If I understand correctly, he's looking for something to plug into jQuery, not an alternative to the whole kaboodle.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [jQuery TOOLS](http://jquerytools.org/) on a few projects; it's focus is to provide a lightweight alternative and both of the components you've mentioned are included.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS and Dojo are good alternative UI libraries, but I wouldn't really consider them smaller than jquery UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind dumping your MVC and DOM manipulation libraries, use YUI.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jqwidgets.com try with jqwidgets. but problem is that it is not free for commercial use.